# ModuleNotFoundError after packaging using setuptools in Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools

I am trying to generate a package from a Python3.6 application using setuptools. While the packaging terminates without errors, the command line program generated by setuptools fail to import modules in the package.
Following is the directory tree of my project.

```
.
├── MANIFEST.in
├── README.md
├── README.rst
├── contributors.txt
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
├── sonicparanoid
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── inpyranoid.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── length_difference_filter.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── ortholog_detection.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── reads_stats.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── seq_tools.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── sonicparanoid.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── sys_tools.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   └── workers.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── bin
│   │   └── mmseqs
│   ├── blast_tools.py
│   ├── compile_inpyranoid_c.py
│   ├── compile_mmseqs_parser_c.py
│   ├── config.json
│   ├── example
│   │   ├── test_input
│   │   │   ├── chlamydia_trachomatis
│   │   │   ├── deinococcus_radiodurans
│   │   │   ├── gloeobacter_violaceus
│   │   │   └── thermotoga_maritima
│   │   └── test_output
│   │       └── README.txt
│   ├── inpyranoid.py
│   ├── inpyranoid_c.c
│   ├── inpyranoid_c.cpython-36m-darwin.so
│   ├── inpyranoid_c.pyx
│   ├── length_difference_filter.py
│   ├── mmseqs2_src
│   │   ├── README.txt
│   │   └── mmseqs.tar.gz
│   ├── mmseqs_parser_c.c
│   ├── mmseqs_parser_c.cpython-36m-darwin.so
│   ├── mmseqs_parser_c.pyx
│   ├── mmseqs_parser_cython.py
│   ├── ortholog_detection.py
│   ├── quick_multi_paranoid
│   │   ├── Makefile
│   │   ├── Makefile.in
│   │   ├── config
│   │   ├── dump.cpp
│   │   ├── gen_header.cpp
│   │   ├── hashtable.c
│   │   ├── hashtable.h
│   │   ├── hashtable.o
│   │   ├── hashtable_itr.c
│   │   ├── hashtable_itr.h
│   │   ├── hashtable_private.h
│   │   ├── ortholog.c
│   │   ├── qa.h
│   │   ├── qa1
│   │   ├── qa1.cpp
│   │   ├── qa2
│   │   ├── qa2.cpp
│   │   ├── qp
│   │   ├── qp.c
│   │   └── qps.c
│   ├── reads_stats.py
│   ├── seq_tools.py
│   ├── setup_sonicparanoid.py
│   ├── sonicparanoid.py
│   ├── sys_tools.py
│   ├── test_blast_tools.py
│   ├── test_length_difference_filter.py
│   ├── test_ortholog_detection.py
│   ├── test_reads_stats.py
│   ├── test_seq_tools.py
│   ├── test_sonicparanoid.py
│   ├── test_sys_tools.py
│   └── workers.py
└── user_manual.pdf
```

If I run `python3 sonicparanoid.py` it works with no problem, but if I create the distribution using setuptools I will get an import errors whenever the main program (sonicparanoid.py) tries to import any other .py module inside the package (sonicparanoid) directory.

Following is the my setup.py:

```
enter code here
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from setuptools.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy

extensions = [
    Extension(
        "sonicparanoid.inpyranoid_c",
        ["sonicparanoid/inpyranoid_c.pyx"],
        include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()],
    ),
    Extension(
        "sonicparanoid.mmseqs_parser_c",
        ["sonicparanoid/mmseqs_parser_c.pyx"],
        include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()],
    ),
]


from codecs import open
from os import path

here = path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__))

# Get the long description from the README file
with open(path.join(here, 'README.rst'), encoding='utf-8') as f:
    long_description = f.read()

setup(
    name='sonicparanoid',
    version='0.0.2',  # Required
    description='Whatever',
    long_description=long_description,  # Optional
    url='http://iwasakilab.bs.s.u-tokyo.ac.jp/sonicparanoid/',  # Optional
    author='Me',
    author_email='my@email.com',
    classifiers=[  # Optional
        'Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable',
        'Environment :: Console',
        'Intended Audience :: Science/Research',
        'Topic :: Scientific/Engineering :: Bio-Informatics',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: GNU General Public License v3 (GPLv3)',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6',
    ],
    packages = ['sonicparanoid',], # Required
    install_requires=['numpy>=1.14.0', 'pandas>=0.22.0', 'cython>=0.27.0',     'sh>=1.12.14', 'setuptools>=24.2.0'], # specify minimum version
    python_requires='>=3.5, <3.7',
    ext_modules = cythonize(extensions, compiler_directives={'language_level': 3}),
    package_dir={'sonicparanoid': 'sonicparanoid/'},
    include_package_data=True,
    package_data={'sonicparanoid': ['example/test_output/*', 'example/test_input/*', 'mmseqs2_src/*', 'quick_multi_paranoid/*']
                },
    entry_points={  # Optional
        'console_scripts': [
            'sonicparanoid = sonicparanoid.sonicparanoid:main',
        ],
    },
)
```

This how the import statements look in `sonicparanoid.py`:

```
import os
import sys
import platform
import seq_tools as seqtools
```

at present everything works fine if I execute `python3 sonicparanoid.py`, but when I use the program generated using setuptools I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/sonicparanoid", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('sonicparanoid==0.0.2', 'console_scripts',     'sonicparanoid')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 572, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2755, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2408, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py",     line 2414, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sonicparanoid-0.0.2-py3.6-    macosx-10.13-x86_64.egg/sonicparanoid/sonicparanoid.py", line 5, in <module>
    import seq_tools as seqtools
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'seq_tools'
```

I have tried to use the solution proposed in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48900903/modulenotfounderror-after-packaging-with-pip/48951605#48951605), 
but if I change the import with, for example `from sonicparanoid import seq_tools as seqtools` and run `python3 sonicparanoid.py` I get an import error `ImportError: cannot import name 'seq_tools'`

Any help would be greatly appreciated, it is my first attempt in packaging and it is quite frustrating.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python uses `sys.path` to find modules/packages and prepends the directory of a script to the beginning of `sys.path`. With this in mind let's me look into details of import.

When you run `python sonicparanoid/sonicparanoid.py` Python adds the directory `sonicparanoid/` to `sys.path`. Now when the directory is in `sys.path` the script can import `seq_tools` directly because the module `seq_tools.py` is in a directory in `sys.path`.

When you install the package and run generated entry point `sonicparanoid` the directory `sonicparanoid/` is not in `sys.path` (but its parent is) and Python cannot import `seq_tools`. You have to import it as `sonicparanoid.seq_tools`. But that means that you cannot import it from `sonicparanoid.py` when you run `sonicparanoid.py` as a script!

Bottom line: don't run `sonicparanoid.py` as a script because `sys.path` is too different from running entry point importing `sonicparanoid` package.

Also you script must not be named the same as a Python package. When you have a package `sonicparanoid` and a script `sonicparanoid.py` and the script tries to `import sonicparanoid` — Python tries to import from the script (because it's the first in `sys.path`) instead of the package and failed.

You can name your script `sonicparanoid` (without `.py` extension Python will not try to import from it) or `sonic_paranoid.py` but not `sonicparanoid.py`.

Comment: Hello @phd, and thank you. I have renamed the main script sonic_paranoid.py as you suggested and now the error is different.
It seems to be now related to the entry_point which I changed to
'sonicparanoid = sonicparanoid.sonic_paranoid:main'. Bt now it seems it cannot find that script at all and exit with the error 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sonicparanoid.sonic_paranoid'.
At this point I am really confused. Please note that I have not change the imports and are still as described in the question.

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sonicparanoid.sonic_paranoid'. And I have changed the entry_point to 'sonicparanoid = sonicparanoid.sonic_paranoid:main'.

Comment: It seems you renamed `sonicparanoid.py` but didn't reinstall the package so it's still `sonicparanoid/sonicparanoid.py` when installed. Is it?

Comment: Hello @phd, and thanks a lot. Its seems that error is gone. I could substitute all the imports with 'from package import module_name as new_name'. The very tricky, and for me unexplicable part is that the python3 interpreter would not allow me to run script in the old fashion with that import style, but after the bdist was built and installed the script could also run in the 'old fashion' way.
Now there are still some problems since I am also using Cython, but it is great that I could solve with your help this starting problem.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Now when it's fixed I updated my answer to provide more details about import. You can rename `sonic_paranoid.py` back to `sonicparanoid.py` but you must not run it as a script.