# Difficulty with cython paths to compile working version of pyx pxd files

Tags: python, cython, setuptools

I got 3 files in cython that represent 2 classes:

```
1. ../src/cython/class1.pyx
2. ../src/cython/class1.pxd
3. ../src/cython/class2.pyx
```

I want to import a class defined in `class1` to `class2` to be able to use cython typing for a custom class.

Inside `class2` if I import `Class1` like this, I can't compile:

```
from src.cython.class1 cimport Class1
```

Inside `class2` if I import `Class1` like below, I can compile but I get error `No module named 'src.cython.class1'` on execution:

```
from class1 cimport Class1
```

I am running `setup.py` from `../`

This question was marked as a possible duplicate of a very different issue. I was getting these errors only because I missed the `__init__.py` in the `cython` folder.

Comment: I'm by no means an expert here, but have you tried writing the full directory?

Comment: @3141 now that you mentioned I tried it without success, thanks anyhow!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ModuleNotFoundError after packaging with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48900903/modulenotfounderror-after-packaging-with-pip)

Comment: Just checking but do you have an `__init__.py` file at each folder level (in your `src` and `cython` folders)?

Comment: 1. What is your directory structure (especially what dirs are packages)? 2. What are the extension names? The sources are irrelevant because you don't import from `pyx` files at runtime, you load code from shared objetcs.

Comment: I was missing a __init__.py in the `..src/cython/` folder. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directory structure should be like this:

1. `../src/cython/class1.pyx`
2. `../src/cython/__init__.pxd`
3. `../src/cython/class1.pxd`
4. `../src/cython/class2.pyx`

In class2.pyx:

```
from class1 cimport Class1
```

The setup.py should have:

```
extensions = [Extension('my_package.cython.class1',
                        <..>
              ),
              Extension('my_package.cython.class2',
                        <..>,
              ),
]
```

The 'no module' error is because the directory names do not match the extension name, in addition to the directory needing to be defined as a package.

`__init__.pxd` is the equivalent to `__init__.py` for `cimport`.